# GCD of two polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the greatest common divisor of each of the following pairs $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ of polynomials. $p(x) = 7x^3 + 6x^2 −8x+ 4$ and $q(x) = x^3 + x− 2$, where $p(x), q(x) \in Q[x]$.

I divided $p(x)$ by $q(x)$ and I got $7$ with the remainder $r_1(x) = 6x^2 - 15x + 18$

then I got completely confused and don't know how to find the $\gcd$ of them.
Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: yes, a(x) and b(x) such that a(x)p(x) + b(x)q(x) = d(x)

Comment: Well, this equality is called [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity#For_polynomials) (which you can get using [extended GCD/Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity_and_extended_GCD_algorithm)). But you don't need to find the polynomials $a(x), b(x)$ (those you mention in the previous comment) in order to find $d(x)$.

Comment: Have you got time to do the Euclidean algorithm I posted in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The basic of Euclidean algorithm more e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). Having the polynomials $p,q$. We calculate
\begin{alignat*}{2}
p &= s_0\cdot q & &+ r_0\\
q &= s_1\cdot r_0 & &+ r_1\\
r_0 &= s_2 \cdot r_1 & &+ r_2\\
&\vdots & &\\
r_{n-3} &= s_{n-1}\cdot r_{n-2} & &+ r_{n-1}\\
r_{n-2} &= s_{n}\cdot r_{n-1} & &+ r_{n}.\\
\end{alignat*}

Each line means dividing one polynomial by other (you dividing $p$ by $q$ is the first row). $s_i$ and $r_j$ are also polynomials. $r_j$ are the remainders after the division. We do those steps while $r_n \neq 0$. If $r_n = 0$ then $\gcd{(p,q)} = r_{n-1}$.

**Euclidean algorithm** for $p(x), q(x)$.
$$
7x^3 + 6x^2 - 8x+4 = 7\cdot (x^3+x-2) + 6x^2-15x + 18
$$
So according to notation in the algorithm above $s_0(x) = 0$ and $r_0(x) = 6x^2-15x + 18$. No we divide $q(x)$ by $r_0(x)$

$$
x^3+x-2 = \left(\frac{1}{6}x + \frac{5}{12}\right)\cdot (6x^2-15x) + \frac{17}{4}x - \frac{19}{2}.
$$

So $s_1(x) = \frac{1}{6}x + \frac{5}{12}$ and $r_1(x) = \frac{17}{4}x - \frac{19}{2}$. Can you continue in this algorithm?

Comment: I did but I got a weird answer and I'm not sure it's correct.

Comment: Well, [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd+7x%5E3+%2B+6x%5E2+-+8x%2B4%2C+x%5E3%2Bx-2) gives $\gcd{(p(x), q(x))=1}$.